# How can I view webpages and save data to a database using Java?

Tags: java, database, string, image

I am collecting data from a website and trying to save it to a database (or something similar that is very accessible) rather than having a heap of files on my desktop or in a folder.

There are many pages that I need to look at (1900 to be exact). I want to save time in getting this data, and decided to make a Java program to do this.

This is basically what I am trying to do.

1. Visit the webpage: www.TestWebsite.com/items/0
2. Save the (Name, Description, Image(png)) into one array/class to a Database.
3. Repeat until I get up to: www.TestWebsite.com/items/1899

I want to be able to access this data offline without having to need to go online to view it.

Any ideas on how I should start. I have made a basic webpage viewer, I am just missing the step in between saving the strings and images to a database.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually just did this the other day. I used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to scrap the webpages I needed and wrote to my local database. awesomely easy framework for webpage parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward, but you'll need to learn a little SQL if you haven't already.

You'll also have to pick a database platform - I'd suggest SQLite for such a purpose, since the data is for personal use and it's lightweight and easy to set up.

Here's a tutorial on using JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) to talk with a SQLite database:  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite.  It goes from setup to inserting data, so once you've completed that it should be straightforward to modify your webpage viewing code to grab the data you need and shove it into the DB.

Good luck!